# Offline and Online indoor map with open street map.

Tags: android, mapbox

I designed indoor map with Josm. I try to doing indoor map project with android.

I made open street map on josm and I asking question about it on [OSM HELP PAGE](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/31993/uploading-josm-indoor-map-on-open-street-map) and they said use tilemill for showing your indoor map. But tilemille suport .shp file and I could not convert it on tilemill. 
you can download my work josm [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wiawbaqpo5zoyos/map%20%284%29.osm)

My question is.

**How can I design this indoor map on mapbox-TileMill. Or Could you give other advise**

[exxample project](https://github.com/unSinn/IndoorNav) and I found this project for example  When I import it **,Why it does not show map**

And **How can I show map on my android application**

could you give me advise. I am so mixed.Could you give me open source project or example

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a way to load .osm map to tilemill there is a way. I did it following instructions in [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-ubuntu-quickstart/). After you have your tiles created using Tilemill you can either either export them to your mapbox account or as mbtiles. Then you can use the [mapbox android sdk](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk) to create your indoor map app.

Another alternative is to use [mapsforge](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/). They provide a mapwriter plugin (which is a plugin for osmosis)that allows you to [convert .osm files into .map files](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter). This .map file can then be loaded into the SD card and be used to render maps. However this option will only allow offline maps.

I hope this helps.